# vncdo send upper, lower case and special character

Tags: python, vnc

I need to send a VNC command including upper, lower case and special character at **the same time**; how to do it? This is what I'm currently using:

```
call(['vncdo --force-caps -s 192.168.1.1::5900 type Admin!23'], shell=True)
```

Seems to only send characters in uppercase.

Using:

- Python 2.7
- vncdotool==0.10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue in VNC server side. vncdtool 0.10 was sending correctly the case and character as specified before.